# What's the Centralizer $ A_{4}/V_{4} $ in $ S_{4} $

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

What's the Centralizer $ A_{4}/V_{4} $ in $ S_{4} $ that $ V_{4} $ is the Klein four-group. If $ G $ is a group, $ H $ and $ K $ is the subgroup of $ G $ such that $ K \unlhd H $, then $ C_{G}(H/K) = \lbrace g\in G \vert [g,h]<K , \quad \forall h\in H \rangle $,.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the derived series of $S_4$ is $$1<V_4<A_4<S_4$$
In particular, $V_4$ is the derived subgroup of $A_4$, so we have that $A_4\subseteq C_{S_4}\left(A_4/V_4\right)$. However, $A_4$ is a maximal subgroup of $S_4$, and $V_4$ is not the derived subgroup of $S_4$, so it must be that $A_4 = C_{S_4}\left(A_4/V_4\right)$.